# Fetching configuration parameters for an existing config service

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm looking to delete an app and all the binded services associated with it. And then create the app and recreate all the services and bind them back.

- What is the ideal method to retrieve all the binded services to the app?
- What is the best way to fetch the configuration parameters for the existing config services?

---

Ref:

- Create App: http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/push.html
- Delete App: http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/delete.html
- Create Service: http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/create-service.html
- Delete Service: http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/delete-service.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deployed your application with using a [manifest file](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html) then all the information you need will be in there.

It's possible though that services were bound/unbound from the application via API, CLI or a UI. You can retrieve a list of the services bound to an application by running `cf env APP_NAME`

Services bound to the application can be found under the `VCAP_SERVICES` object. You can then parse that object for all services, delete and then recreate them all.

Comment: cool.. yes.. I followed you till the point of extracting the VCAP_SERVICES object. This object doesn't give us the config params that were used to create the services. For eg. A config server I created was configured with git so it had `-c {'git': {...} }` in it. Is there any way to get that information?

Comment: sorry I didn't read your full question so missed the second part. As far as I'm aware it's not possible. You'd have to keep a record of that somehow yourself. Even the service instance api (https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/272/service_instances/retrieve_a_particular_service_instance.html) doesn't seem to return any custom config. I just tested it right now.

Comment: although this answers the question, I'm still curious - how does that information is then visible on the front end.. I'm using GAIA and it does display that info.. isnt it internally using some service to fetch that data?